# Why you would consider using Ruby instead of JRuby if already having a Java environment?

Tags: java, ruby, performance, comparison, jruby

I know there are some differences between both of them, but suppossing that you already have a fully-operating Java environment for developing, testing and production, will you ever consider using Ruby MRI instead of JRuby? On top of that, I would also argue that you can inline Java, use Java datatypes and, most importantly, it almost always outperform Ruby. What do you think? Is there any reason why one should consider Ruby seriously when compared to JRuby?

Comment: Are you talking about using the JRuby implementation to run plain Ruby programs, or using JRuby-specific features?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about choice. If JRuby makes more sense to you use it. Using MRI means you're using Ruby the way Matz has intended it.

This should also answer the question for Rubinius, Maglev and all other implementations. Each serves a different purpose and tries to cover all aspects of MRI. To achieve that they (all) use RubySpec to test the implementation against MRI.